# select value of <select> tags with the onchange(this.value)

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I am trying to get the value of the selection on each change, I tried to log it to the console in my javascript but it doesn't work, this is some of the code from the problem...  I am new to programming Please keep the answer simple... Thanks

```js
function add(x) {
    var selection = x;
    console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<select class="seletion" onchange="add(this.value)">
                <option value="a">A</option>
                <option value="b">B</option>
                <option value="c">C</option>
                <option value="d">D</option>
                <option value="e">E</option>
                <option value="f">F</option>
                <option value="g">G</option>
                <option value="h">H</option>
                <option value="i">I</option>
                <option value="j">J</option>
                <option value="k">K</option>
                <option value="l">L</option>
                <option value="m">M</option>
                <option value="n">N</option>
                <option value="o">O</option>
                <option value="p">P</option>
                <option value="q">Q</option>
                <option value="r">R</option>
                <option value="s">S</option>
                <option value="t">T</option>
                <option value="u">U</option>
                <option value="v">V</option>
                <option value="w">W</option>
                <option value="x">X</option>
                <option value="y">Y</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: What do you mean *"It doesn't work"*? You cannot use the function name `add`

Comment: Click the Run code snippet and select something. You'll see the error.

Comment: Yes the console is blank... I don't understand why it's still blank, it should display the value on each change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***ANSWER UPDATE***

Reading from [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) you can see a method:

> add()  Adds an element to the collection of option elements for this select element.

This is the function called and not yours.

Indeed, you can see this in the following example:

```js
var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
opt1.value = "1";
opt1.text = "Option: Value 1";

function add (x) {
  var selection = x;
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<select class="seletion" onchange="add(opt1);console.log('New option added at the end')">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
    <option value="e">E</option>
    <option value="f">F</option>
    <option value="g">G</option>
    <option value="h">H</option>
    <option value="i">I</option>
    <option value="j">J</option>
    <option value="k">K</option>
    <option value="l">L</option>
    <option value="m">M</option>
    <option value="n">N</option>
    <option value="o">O</option>
    <option value="p">P</option>
    <option value="q">Q</option>
    <option value="r">R</option>
    <option value="s">S</option>
    <option value="t">T</option>
    <option value="u">U</option>
    <option value="v">V</option>
    <option value="w">W</option>
    <option value="x">X</option>
    <option value="y">Y</option>
</select>
```

The name of your function **add** is considered a different function from JS.

Change its name, for example, to add1 or call it as a global function attached to the window object:

```js
function add1(x) {
  var selection = x;
  console.log('add1: ' + x);
}

function add(x) {
  var selection = x;
  console.log('window.add: ' + x);
}
```

```html
<select class="seletion" onchange="add1(this.value);">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
    <option value="e">E</option>
    <option value="f">F</option>
    <option value="g">G</option>
    <option value="h">H</option>
    <option value="i">I</option>
    <option value="j">J</option>
    <option value="k">K</option>
    <option value="l">L</option>
    <option value="m">M</option>
    <option value="n">N</option>
    <option value="o">O</option>
    <option value="p">P</option>
    <option value="q">Q</option>
    <option value="r">R</option>
    <option value="s">S</option>
    <option value="t">T</option>
    <option value="u">U</option>
    <option value="v">V</option>
    <option value="w">W</option>
    <option value="x">X</option>
    <option value="y">Y</option>
</select>



<select class="seletion" onchange="window.add(this.value);">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
    <option value="e">E</option>
    <option value="f">F</option>
    <option value="g">G</option>
    <option value="h">H</option>
    <option value="i">I</option>
    <option value="j">J</option>
    <option value="k">K</option>
    <option value="l">L</option>
    <option value="m">M</option>
    <option value="n">N</option>
    <option value="o">O</option>
    <option value="p">P</option>
    <option value="q">Q</option>
    <option value="r">R</option>
    <option value="s">S</option>
    <option value="t">T</option>
    <option value="u">U</option>
    <option value="v">V</option>
    <option value="w">W</option>
    <option value="x">X</option>
    <option value="y">Y</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank's i understand why was getting nothing in the console now...!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this : Your code looks good to me but somehow function name add is not working, once i change the name of function it starts working, see working snippet

```js
function showSelection(x) {
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
    <select class="seletion" onchange="showSelection(this.value);">
                    <option value="a">A</option>
                    <option value="b">B</option>
                    <option value="c">C</option>
                    <option value="d">D</option>
                    <option value="e">E</option>
                    <option value="f">F</option>
                    <option value="g">G</option>
                    <option value="h">H</option>
                    <option value="i">I</option>
                    <option value="j">J</option>
                    <option value="k">K</option>
                    <option value="l">L</option>
                    <option value="m">M</option>
                    <option value="n">N</option>
                    <option value="o">O</option>
                    <option value="p">P</option>
                    <option value="q">Q</option>
                    <option value="r">R</option>
                    <option value="s">S</option>
                    <option value="t">T</option>
                    <option value="u">U</option>
                    <option value="v">V</option>
                    <option value="w">W</option>
                    <option value="x">X</option>
                    <option value="y">Y</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Passing `this` or `this.value` isn't the problem. The problem is the choice of function name. I would recommend testing your answer before submitting them.

Comment: @NewToJS, yeah i agree with you. Name of function is the cause to problem. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank's...!!  I understand the issue now

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more reliable solution

```js
function addsel() {
    var selection = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    console.log(selection);
}
```

```html
<select id="sel1" class="seletion" onchange="addsel()">
                <option value="a">A</option>
                <option value="b">B</option>
                <option value="c">C</option>
                <option value="d">D</option>
                <option value="e">E</option>
                <option value="f">F</option>
                <option value="g">G</option>
                <option value="h">H</option>
                <option value="i">I</option>
                <option value="j">J</option>
                <option value="k">K</option>
                <option value="l">L</option>
                <option value="m">M</option>
                <option value="n">N</option>
                <option value="o">O</option>
                <option value="p">P</option>
                <option value="q">Q</option>
                <option value="r">R</option>
                <option value="s">S</option>
                <option value="t">T</option>
                <option value="u">U</option>
                <option value="v">V</option>
                <option value="w">W</option>
                <option value="x">X</option>
                <option value="y">Y</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: I would recommend explaining why this is more "reliable" and why. Dumping source code with no explanation isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: and it would be more helpful if you could tell why my code is not working... Thanks again...!!

Comment: @user2777173 I have explained in the comment below your question. You cannot use the function name `add` as it's already being used. **gaetanoM** answer also explains this and gives you two examples.

Comment: Thank You...!! I Understand the issue now

Answer (score 1):

Using in-line event handlers is not always the best idea.
Why not try using the DOM API to handle this scenario?

Remove the 'onchange' handler in the `<select>`
then add the following to your JS script

```
document.getElementsByClassName('seletion')[0].addEventListener('change', function(){      
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

Comment: But this isn't explaining the problem with the existing source code.... is it....

Comment: I am trying to discourage the use of a bad practice and provide an alternative solution to their problem.

Comment: Well I would recommend explaining why the existing source code isn't working/functioning before offering a solution that has such a change. When making a change like this you might find you will need to explain your answer/solution in more detail.